# perl + numeration word or parameter in file

Tags: perl

I need help about how to numeration text in file.

I have also linux machine and I need to write the script with perl

I have file name: file_db.txt

In this file have parameters like name,ParameterFromBook,NumberPage,BOOK_From_library,price etc
Each parameter equal to something as name=elephant

My question How to do this by perl

I want to give number for each parameter (before the "=") that repeated (unique parameter) in the file , and increase by (+1) the new number of the next repeated parameter until EOF

lidia

For example

file_db.txt before numbering

```
    parameter=1
    name=one

    parameter=2
    name=two
```

file_db.txt after parameters numbering

```
    parameter1=1
    name1=one

    parameter2=2
    name2=two
```

- other examples

Example1 before

```
    name=elephant
    ParameterFromBook=234
    name=star.world
    ParameterFromBook=200
    name=home_room1
    ParameterFromBook=264
```

Example1 after parameters numbering

```
    name1=elephant
    ParameterFromBook1=234
    name2=star.world
    ParameterFromBook2=200
    name3=home_room1
    ParameterFromBook3=264
```

Example2 before

file_db.txt before numbering

```
       lines_and_words=1
       list_of_books=3442

       lines_and_words=13
       list_of_books=344224

       lines_and_words=120
       list_of_books=341
```

Example2 after

file_db.txt after parameters numbering

```
        lines_and_words1=1
        list_of_books1=3442

        lines_and_words2=13
        list_of_books2=344224

        lines_and_words3=120
        list_of_books3=341
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be condensed to a one line perl script pretty easily, though I don't particularly recommend it if you want readability:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
s/(.*)=/$k{$1}++;"$1$k{$1}="/e and print while <>;
```

This version reads from a specified file, rather than using the command line:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open IN, "/tmp/file";
s/(.*)=/$k{$1}++;"$1$k{$1}="/e and print while <IN>;
```

Comment: its work fine ( but I need to know if this script is believable)


please your advice 
lidia

Comment: what I need to change if I want to put the PATH : /tmp/file
in plcae to give argument to the script?

Comment: By readability I mean the script may not be easy to understand if you're unfamiliar with perl.

I'm not sure I understand your other question.

Comment: the second question is that I don't want to use argument , I need to set the PATH=/tmp/file , in order the script will read from file and not from the argument , please help

Comment: final remark can you please advice how to write the output to somefile?
lidia

Comment: @pdehann : its hard to understand even if you DO understand Perl, mostly because of the massive terseness you've needlessly employed. Also, 1) use '`open my $fh`' not '`open IN`'  ( lexical file handles ) 2) use 3-arg-open ( `open my $fh, '<', '/tmp/file'` )   3) check for open failure  ( `open my $fh, '<' , '/tmp/file' or die $@;` )

Answer (score 1):

The way I look at it, you probably want to number *blocks* and not just occurrences. So you probably want the number on each of the keys to be at least as great as the earliest repeating key.

```
my $in  = \*::DATA;  
my $out = \*::STDOUT;
my %occur;
my $num = 0;
while ( <$in> ) {
    if ( my ( $pre, $key, $data ) = m/^(\s*)(\w+)=(.*)/ ) { 
        $num++ if $num < ++$occur{$key};
        print { $out } "$pre$key$num=$data\n";
    }
    else {
        $num++;
        print;
    }
}
__DATA__
    name=elephant
    ParameterFromBook=234
    name=star.world
    ParameterFromBook=200
    name=home_room1
    ParameterFromBook=264
```

However, if you just wanted to give the key it's particular count. This is enough:

```
my %occur;
while ( <$in> ) {
    my ( $pre, $key, $data ) = m/^(\s*)(\w+)=(.*)/;
    $occur{$key}++;
    print { $out } "$pre$key$occur{$key}=$data\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in pretty much pseudo code:

```
open(DATA, "file");
my @lines = <DATA>;
my %tags;
foreach line (@lines)
{
    my %parts=split(/=/, $line);
    my $name=$parts[0];
    my $value=$parts[1];

    $name = ${name}$tags{ $name };
    $tags{ $name } = $tags{ $name } + 1;
    printf "${name}=$value\n";
}
close( DATA );
```

This looks like a CS101 assignment. Is it really good to ask for complete solutions instead of asking specific technical questions if you have difficulty?

Comment: @lidia As n-alexander said, it's pseudo-code (sort of). The idea is that _you_ now turn it into a final solution. We're not here to write code for you.

Comment: I begin to lern perl
so if you can please help me?

Comment: @lidia The best way to learn is to read and try. Post back if you have _specific_ problems. Otherwise, it looks like you're not trying to learn, you're trying to get code. Here's a good (and free) introductory book http://www.perl.org/books/beginning-perl/

Comment: Also, don't use examples like this for learning Perl, go read beginning perl like @Telemachus said. That 'open DATA, "file"' notation is not only *old* but *dangerous* to use in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

If Perl is not a must, here's an awk version

```
$ cat  file
    name=elephant
    ParameterFromBook=234
    name=star.world
    ParameterFromBook=200
    name=home_room1
    ParameterFromBook=264

$ awk -F"=" '{s[$1]++}{print $1s[$1],$2}' OFS="=" file
    name1=elephant
    ParameterFromBook1=234
    name2=star.world
    ParameterFromBook2=200
    name3=home_room1
    ParameterFromBook3=264
```

Comment: how to build the awk in the perl script?

Comment: I mentioned that if you are not restricted to Perl, you can use this awk one liner. Otherwise, look at the other Perl answers for inspiration

Comment: is it possible to integrated it with system?

Comment: you mean Perl's system() ? yes of course, but don't do that please. There are many Perl answers here. Go and have them tested out.

Comment: hi
I run the system("  awk -F"=" '{s[$1]++}{print $1s[$1],$2}' OFS="=" file " );   but I get errors? like Can't modify string in scalar assignment at

Comment: you'll have to learn a bit more Perl before you can put such a command into a system() call. It's not easy