# perl + print to file_out in place to standard output

Tags: perl

I have the follwoing script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
open IN, "/tmp/file"; 
s/(.*)=/$k{$1}++;"$1$k{$1}="/e and print while <IN>;
```

how to print the output of the script to file_out in place to print to standard output?

lidia

Comment: possible duplicate of [perl +  numeration word or parameter in file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290398/perl-numeration-word-or-parameter-in-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
open IN, "/tmp/file"; 
open OUT, ">file_out.txt";
s/(.*)=/$k{$1}++;"$1$k{$1}="/e and print OUT while <IN>;
```

Explanation:

- `open IN, "/tmp/file"

  - `open` command to open file
  - `IN` filehandle name
  - `/tmp/file` name of file and specifier that it is for reading

    - if there is no modifier, it means reading
    - if there is a `<`, i.e. `"</tmp/file"` it also means reading
- `open OUT, ">file_out.txt"

  - `open` command to open file
  - `OUT` filehandle name
  - `>file_out.txt` name of file and specifier that it is for reading

    - there must be a `>`, i.e. `">file_out.txt"` to write
- `s/.../.../e` your substitution (I assume you know what it does)
- `and` is a boolean operator that [short-circuits](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-And), meaning it only does the thing afterwards if the thing beforehand is true. In this case, it will only print if the substitution actually matched something.
- `print OUT` print to the filehandle `OUT`
- `while <IN>` for each line from the file behind filehandle `IN`

Note:

Used this way, it makes extensive use of the magical default variable `$_`. Do a search for `$_` on the [perlintro](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html) site. In short:

- If you don't tell a `s///` substitution what string to work on, it uses `$_`
- If you don't tell a `print` what to print, it prints `$_`
- If you don't tell a `while` loop going through a filehandle's data where to put each line, it gets put into `$_`

Your program could have been rewritten:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
open IN, "/tmp/file"; 
open OUT, ">file_out.txt";
while( defined( $line = <IN> ) )
{
  $line =~ s/(.*)=/$k{$1}++;"$1$k{$1}="/e or next;
  print OUT $line;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the filehandle you are printing to after the `print` statement; opening for writing is a small change from opening for reading:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
open IN, "/tmp/file";
open OUT, '>', "/tmp/file_out";
s/(.*)=/Sk_$1_++;"$1Sk_$1_="/ and print OUT while <IN>;
```

(I munged the replacement a bit, so it was easier for me to test.)

Comment: I get an error : readline() on closed filehandle IN at ./stam101 line 4.

Comment: Hrm, I don't get that error message here; try re-writing to `while(<IN>) { s/.../.../e and print OUT; }` and see if that helps?